# iOSのApp内課金で「There's no information available for In-App Purchases.Try again later.21105」と表示される

Tags: swift, xcode, アプリ内課金

数日前までは何もエラーが出なかったXCodeのiOS向けのプロジェクトをビルドすると、急に「There's no information available for In-App Purchases.Try again later.21105」と表示されるようになりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

過去に普通に開けていて全く変更のなかったコードやプロジェクトのバックをビルドしてもこのエラーが出るので、Certificates(契約更新等)に問題があるのかと思って契約更新について調べてみました。
すると、契約は明日の8月26日まで有効であったものの、もしかしたらこれが原因かもしれないと思い契約の更新を行いました。

しかし、特に変化はなく同様のエラーが出続けています。

契約更新については以下の動画を参考に「iOS Development」と「App Store」のProfileへの登録を行いました。
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v19ZoFa1cJs

1つ動画内で気になる点があるとしたらXCodeのProvisioning Profileという項目には変更できなかった点くらいです。
(まだ期限が切れていないせいかStatusで赤色の警告などが出ていませんでした)

課金周りは、SwiftyStoreKitというライブラリを使用しております。
XCodeのバージョンは、Version 11.6 (11E708)を使用しております。

このようなエラーはどのような条件で出るものなのでしょうか？
また、どうしたら出さなくすることができるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どうも最近、Appleの認証サーバーに問題が起きているようでTestFlight上でのみこのエラーが出るようです。
英語版のスタックオーバーフローで同様の事例が報告されていました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610039/there-is-no-information-available-for-in-app-purchases-try-again-later-21105